# Select case menu not working

Tags: bash, unix, select, scripting, switch-statement

I have the following select menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice(1-4): '
options=("First Install" "Add cilent" "Delete Cilent" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "First Install")
            newinstall
            break
            ;;
        "Add cilent")
            add_client
            break
            ;;
        "Delete Cilent")
            delete_client
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

The issue is that when i enter `2` i get `invalid option` message whereas all other cases work.

Comment: Probably a typo, or a problem in `add_client`. Your `select` works for me

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the code you're running? It woks for me. Did you really spell "Client" as "Cilent" in both the cases?

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov you were right it was a typo

Comment: To avoid this typos I suggest to replace `"First Install")` by `"${options[0]}")` and `"Add cilent")` by `"${options[1]}")` etc.

Comment: @Cyrus great suggestion...post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid typos I suggest to use strings of array `options` only once in your code. Replace `"First Install")` by `"${options[0]}")` and `"Add cilent")` by `"${options[1]}")` etc.:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your choice(1-4): '
options=("First Install" "Add cilent" "Delete Cilent" "Quit")

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
  case $opt in
    "${options[0]}")
        newinstall
        break
        ;;
    "${options[1]}")
        add_client
        break
        ;;
    "${options[2]}")
        delete_client
        break
        ;;
    "${options[3]}")
        break
        ;;
    *) echo invalid option;;
  esac
done
```